# How to save XMLobject in memcahe in Zend Framwork2

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-parsing, zend-framework2, memcached

Below is my part of code(in `ZF2`) where I am trying to save an XML object into `Memcache`, But I am unable to figure it out why its not setting up Complex obejct into `Memcache`, Any lead ?

```
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $xmlAclConfigCache = $serviceManager->get('memcache')->getItem('xmlConfig');

        if (empty($xmlAclConfigCache)) {
            echo 'fresh ACL XML';
            $xmlAclConfigCache   = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__.'/config/acl.xml');
            $serviceManager->get('memcache')->setItem('xmlConfig', $xmlAclConfigCache);

            var_dump($xmlAclConfigCache);
        } else {
            echo 'OLD ACL XML';
        }
```

`Memcache` config in **cache.local.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    'caches' => array(
        'memcache' => array( //can be called directly via SM in the name of 'memcached'
            'adapter' => array(
                'name'     =>'memcache',
                'ttl' => 7200,
                'options'  => array(
                    'servers'   => array(
                        array(
                            '127.0.0.1',11211
                        )
                    ),
                    'namespace'  => 'MYMEMCACHEDNAMESPACE',
                )
            ),
            'plugins' => array(
                'exception_handler' => array(
                    'throw_exceptions' => false
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What is the configuration of your memcache service?

Comment: @akond configured as a service manager

Comment: I mean show the configuration.

Comment: @akond added please see the edit

Comment: My guess is the config lacks plugin "serializer".